# can't display video after upload it on SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, video-streaming

I'd like to display a file uploaded on SQL Server.
I did that with success when the file is an image(jpg, gif, png, ...)
But after upload a video on SQL server, I can't display and play it like [this Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLE6.png) looks.

Bellow are:

The servlet **DisplayThoughtFile.java**

```html
public class DisplayThoughtFile extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4593558495041379082L;
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        InputStream sImage;
        try 
        {
            String id = request.getParameter("ThoughtFileId");
            Connection con = Database.getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String strSql = "select thoughtFilePath from thought where thoughtId='" + id + "' ";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSql);
            if (rs.next())
            {
                byte[] bytearray = new byte[1048576];
                int size = 0;
                sImage = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
                response.reset();
                response.setContentType("video/quicktime");
                while ((size = sImage.read(bytearray)) != -1) 
                {
                    response.getOutputStream().write(bytearray, 0, size);
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The page **thought.xhtml**

```html
 <h:outputLink value="DisplayThoughtFile?ThoughtFileId=#{item.tId}" target="_blank" >
    <h:graphicImage value="DisplayThoughtFile?ThoughtFileId=#{item.tId}" width="50" height="50"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

I added to **web.xml**

```html
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DisplayThoughtFile</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DisplayThoughtFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.esprit.chat.beans.DisplayThoughtFile</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DisplayThoughtFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DisplayThoughtFile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Have you please any idea about solving that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: SQL Injection alert....your code is wide open to sql injection. You need to parameterize this query (and all your others) before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: The other issue is why would you think you can display a video in an image object? This object is NOT a video it is the html img object which is for displaying images. You should be able to display an animated gig, but not an actual video.

Comment: Hello Sir @SeanLange, I have the reference of this tutorial http://www.javaknowledge.info/upload-and-display-image-from-mysql-db-using-primefaces/, Is this false ?.

Comment: No that looks accurate. But it is for an image, not a video. Images and videos are not the same thing. It is like the difference between a photograph and a movie. They both can reflect realistic depictions but they are vastly different in how the behave.

Comment: Ok Sir, could you please give me an idea how to do that with video, I'd like to recuperate a video uploaded on DataBase to looks like the video displayed by this link http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml and so I can play it.

Comment: The link you posted has the code for doing this.